# Is it possible that a data returned by the javascript can modify the css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-experience

I would like to understand if it is possible instead to make sure that a data collected with the javascript part can modify one in the css specifically based on a number returned by the javascript code you change the speed of the transitions in the css (I put the js code created below from ***@elikoga***)

```js
// script to check how long a button has been pressed
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const div = document.querySelector('div');

let startTime;
let endTime;

// attach event listener to button
button.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  startTime = new Date();
});

// attach event listener to button
button.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  endTime = new Date();
  const timeDiff = endTime - startTime;
  div.textContent = `You pressed the button for ${timeDiff} milliseconds`;
});
<button>Press me!</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Consider adding punctuation to your question as an incentive for more people to read and respond to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  you can change a lot of things. Your question is super general, so it is hard to help you accurately.

this is how to set the animation duration with javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.animationDuration = "3s";
```

Comment: thanks, to be more precise I would like that for example if the time is close to 44 milliseconds in the CSS the transition of an animation will become 0.4 s instead of 6s, or as the milliseconds it takes to click the button increases, the value of the seconds of the transition in the CSS

Comment: this is how to set the animation duration document.getElementById("myDIV").style.animationDuration = "3s";
so you can use it with any other function or condition. 

if (somecriteria) {
this is how to set the animation duration document.getElementById("myDIV").style.animationDuration = "13s";
} else {
do other things
}